# C++ iterators how to implement next() and previous() functions

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am writing a utility class that contains a vector of things. I want to provide accessor navigation functions to the caller classes. For example,

```
class MyIterator {

public:
  typedef std::vector<someObj>::iterator itr;

  itr next() { return things_.begin(); }
  itr next(itr) { return std::next(itr); }

private:
  std::vector<someObj> things_;
}
```

I have two questions here:

- Is this this the correct way of doing this, or any simple method available?  I am not particularly comfortable with overloading the next() with and without itr.
- In this situation, how does the caller detect the end of iteration?  caller doesn't have access to vector, and hence can't call v.end().  So, should I provide another fn for this check?  If so, it looks to be an overkill.

Surely, I am missing something here...

Comment: What is wrong with `begin`, `end` and `operator ++`?

Comment: Nothing wrong.  Just that they are "inside" the wrapper class MyIterator, and so the vector is not visible/accessible to the caller directly.  Trying to see, what it would take to build custom accessor fns like next() and prev()

Comment: Stick to the normal C++ iterator interface – that way you can reuse existing code with your own class.

Comment: Your `next()` functions will not work for `const MyIterator` objects, as you would need a `const_iterator` to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it right.  All you really need to export is begin() and end().

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct SomeObj
{
  int i;
};

class MyVector {

public:
  using itr = std::vector<SomeObj>::iterator;
  using citr = std::vector<SomeObj>::const_iterator;

  itr begin() { return things_.begin(); }
  itr end()   { return things_.end(); }
  citr begin() const { return things_.begin(); }
  citr end() const   { return things_.end(); }

private:
  std::vector<SomeObj> things_;
};

int main()
{
    MyVector objs;
    for (auto& obj : objs)
    {
    // ....
    }

    std::for_each(objs.begin(), objs.end(), [](auto& o) { o.i = 1;});

    for (auto i = objs.begin(); i != objs.end(); ++i)
    {
       i->i = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```